# How to change characters on gridview while exporting to Excel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview, replace

I want to export Excel. I can export it with below codes but i want to see turkish characters on excel or changing turkish characters to english characters.

I am trying to do it 2 for loops but it is not success. Help me for changing characters.

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < GridView1.Rows.Count; j++)
    {
        GridView1.Rows[j].Cells[i].Text.Replace("ş", "s");
        GridView1.Rows[j].Cells[i].Text.Replace("ı", "i");
        GridView1.Rows[j].Cells[i].Text.Replace("İ", "ı");
        GridView1.Rows[j].Cells[i].Text.Replace("ğ", "g");
    }
}

Response.ClearContent();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", 
                   string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "Görüşmeler.xls"));
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

//Change the Header Row back to white color
GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
//Applying stlye to gridview header cells
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
{
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Style.Add("background-color", "#CCCCFF");
}

GridView1.RenderControl(htw);
Response.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.End();
```

Comment: I do not understand how rendering an HTML grid can produce a _valid_ XLS file.

Comment: i can create xls file with this code but i want to string replace before i do it.

Comment: If you take a look with a text editor at your resulting XLS file, I strongly doubt that it is an XLS file.

Comment: @UweKeim it's a html table, and excel knows how to read html table. That "feature" is root of many evil

Comment: @newusereser do your self a favor and use proper excel library, IMO the best ones are NPOI (xls) and Epplus (xslx), both free and open source and working great. Think about your http response, it looks malicious, you said in headers that you are returning XLS file and in fact you are returning html. It just matter of time when will some antivirus or similar block your response

Comment: i tried it interop library before but i could not use this action on client machine so i needed to try new thing and now no problem its all solved thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You to assign the value from the `Replace` method bat to the cell text:

```
GridView1.Rows[j].Cells[i].Text = GridView1.Rows[j].Cells[i].Text.Replace("ş", "s");
```